# Navigate and wait for webbrowser response with sendkeys

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control, sendkeys

Is it possible to open webpage, navigate once/click button and navigate page for the second time without having to use three buttons (everytihing is working fine with three buttons)?

I tried sleep (doesn't work) and SendKeys.SendWait (also not working).

Here is the code :

```
Dim browser As New WebBrowser
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        With browser
            browser.Name = "mybrowser"
            .Dock = DockStyle.Fill
            .Url = New Uri("http://pretraga2.apr.gov.rs/ObjedinjenePretrage/Search/Search")
            .Visible = True
        End With
        Me.Controls.Add(browser)
        browser.Focus()
        'browser.Focus()
        SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}" & "{TAB}" & "08727988" & "{ENTER}") ' & "{TAB}" & "{ENTER}")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        browser.Focus()
        SendKeys.Send("{TAB}" & "{TAB}" & "20084693" & "{ENTER}") ' & "{TAB}" & "{ENTER}")
        SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}" & "{TAB}" & "{TAB}" & "{TAB}" & "{ENTER}")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        browser.Focus()
        SendKeys.Send("{TAB}" & "{TAB}" & "{TAB}" & "{TAB}" & "{ENTER}")
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes I think this is possible, but you have to wait till the browser finished loading. What browser-control do you use? I used SHDocVw.InternetExplorer in this example:

```
 Public Sub browse(ByVal szURL As String, Optional ByVal bWaitTillDone As Boolean = True)

    Dim nTickStart As Long
    Dim nTickEnde As Long = 0

    Dim i As Integer = 0

    Do
        Try

            IE.Navigate(szURL)

            If bWaitTillDone Then

                nTickStart = System.Environment.TickCount

                While IE.Busy
                    fnSleepMS(15)

                    nTickEnde = System.Environment.TickCount
                    If nTickEnde - nTickStart > IEBrowser.nMaxWaitSeconds * 1000 Then
                        Throw New Exception("Browse hat zu lange gedauert!")
                    End If

                End While
            End If

            Exit Do

        Catch ex As Exception
            i += 1
            If i >= 5 Then
                Throw New Exception("IEBrowser.browse(): " & szURL & "--> " & ex.Message)
            Else
                LOG.add("IEBrowser.browse() - Versuch (" & i & ")" & ex.Message)
                fnSleep(1, LOG)
            End If
        End Try
    Loop

End Sub
```

Using this browser-control you can read out all ahref-Tags and Buttons and click them directly, so you are able to build up a sequence.

Hope I understood you right and this helps a bit. But please tell which browser-control you are using an in which environment (Framework + Visual Studio)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am using Framework 4.5, VS Express 2013 and standard webrowser. I am not that experienced to fix missing variables in your code IE, fnSleepMS, IEBrowser, sorry.

Comment: Then it should work with accessing the "DOM". I have no examples, but I know that you can access each html-control programmatically.

Comment: I see now that I have to install SHDocVw library, but can not find it/

Comment: I think it will also work with the WebBrowser Control and DOM. Check this out: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/85847/HTML-DOM-Using-NET

Comment: Thank you for the link, I gonna need that in the future, but if I understood correctly, DOM is used to extract specific data from HTML page. In my example that is not possible. Part of the link for the last page (last click) is generated 'randomly' so I can not extract final link from HTML source. Only thing that I could, do in example above, is to navigate it with Sendkeys until final page is opened (final link revealed).